# Code with set of options to print contact list, number of contacts, average age of contacts and how many of each type of contact

Tags: java, arrays

I have 3 options in this code and my other classes are set up correctly as far as I can tell. Option 1 and 3 seem to work fine but with option 2 I want it to print the number of contacts (which it does already), print the number of each type of contact, i.e. Personal or Business, and then print the average age of all the contacts. I can't figure out how to get the average age or how to print each type.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PlannerMain {
    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Contact[] contacts = new Contact[6];
    contacts[0] = new PersonalContact("Joe Smith, ", 33, ", 100 Evergreen Ave, ", "Seattle,", "WA ", 98999); // Personal
    contacts[1] = new PersonalContact("Lawrence Williams, ", 45, ", 2000 1st St, ", "Tacoma,", "WA ", 98100); // Personal
    contacts[2] = new PersonalContact("Rachel Garcia, ", 12, ", 12 Forest Drive, ", "Los Angelos,", "CA ", 99301); // Personal
    contacts[3] = new BusinessContact("Gregory Smith, ", 67, ", 360-888-7777", " 360-555-6666"); // Business
    contacts[4] = new BusinessContact("Jerome Bradley, ", 18, ", 216-111-2222", " 253-444-7777"); // Business
    contacts[5] = new BusinessContact("Susie Adams, ", 23, ", 253-333-7777", " 425-666-9999"); // Business

    while (true) {

        System.out.println("1.Print planner contacts. ");
        System.out.println("2.Print planner statistics. ");
        System.out.println("3.Exit.");

        int option = scanner.nextInt();

        if (option == 1) { // Displays every contact in the list until the length of the list has been reached

            for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(contacts[i]);

            } // End for
        } // End option 1

        else if (option == 2) { 
            int sum = 0;
            System.out.println("Number of contacts: " + contacts.length);

            for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++){
                sum += contacts[i];
                }
            System.out.println("Average age: " + (sum / contacts.length));

              if(contacts[] instanceof PersonalContact){             
                for (int i = 0; i < PersonalContact.getLength(); i++){
                    System.out.println("Personal Contacts: " + personalContacts.length);
                }// End for PC
               }//End if PC

              if(contacts[] instanceof BusinessContact){             
                for (int i = 0; i < BusinessContact.getLength(); i++){
                    System.out.println("BusinessContacts: " + businessContacts.length);
                }// End for BC
               }//End if BC

        } // End option 2

        else if (option == 3) { /** Terminates the program */
            System.exit(0);
        } // End option 3
    } // End while


}// End void main
```

}// End

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the average age currently you are using a sum variable and attempting to add contacts[i] to it for every Contact in contacts.  What you actually want is to add the age of each Contact to sum, using something like

```
sum += contacts[i].getAge()
```

or

```
sum += contacts[i].age
```

depending on how the Contact class is implemented.

To get the number of PersonalContacts and BusinessContacts you can do something like:

```
int personalContactsCount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    if (contacts[i] instanceof PersonalContact) {
        personalContactsCount++;
    }
}  
int businessContactsCount = contacts.length - personalContactsCount;
```

Comment: Thanks @Spencer that cleared it up for me. Seems kind of simple now, haha